# python file writing shows the error for UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, utf-8, encode, shift-jis

I need to make the cp932 (it is expanded `shift-jis`)

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u270c' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence`

```
    import codecs
    mytext = '\u270c'
    with codecs.open(path,mode='w',encoding='cp932') as f:
        mytext.encode('cp932',"ignore")
        f.write(mytext)
    exit()
```

I just simplify the `mytext` for this article.

I think this character pass the encode with ignore flg.

However, `write` shows the error.

Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: Code works fine on my computer even without codecs works fine

Comment: Put the `errors='ignore'` flag in the `open()` function. Note: your statement `mytext.encode(...)` throws away the return value; `mytext` is not changed.

Comment: `cp932` doesn't support `'\u270c'` (VICTORY HAND, ✌).

Answer (score 0):

`\` is functional symbol in cp932. So, If you want to encode `\` you should use the `\\` 
in your case :

```
import codecs
mytext = '\\u270c'
with codecs.open(path,mode='w',encoding='cp932') as f:
    mytext.encode('cp932',"ignore")
    f.write(mytext)
exit()
```

Comment: `'\u270c'` and `'\\u270c'` are two different things.

Comment: @lenz I can't understand what you mean ... that code works as his intention.

Comment: Encoding isn't the same thing as escaping. The OP asked about encoding, you're talking about escaping. `'\u270c'` is a single-character string, but when you escape the backslash as `'\\u270c'`, you get a string with six characters – check `len('\u270c'), len('\\u270c')`. When you *encode* either of the strings, you get a `bytes` object (not `str` anymore); the length depends on the encoding chosen.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that difference... I'm still a beginner. I'm ashamed of myself. thank you lenz.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the file `f` will expect Unicode strings to be passed to `f.write()` and they will be encoded as declared by `codecs.open`, so the code is trying to double-encode.  Also, `'\u270c'` is not a character supported by CP932, so it can't be written to a CP932 file in any case.

Assuming Python 3, to write a Unicode string `text` in a particular encoding, use:

```
with open('output.txt','w',encoding='cp932') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

`codecs` is an older module and isn't needed.  In Python 2, `io.open` is the backported equivalent to Python 3's `open` and is also supported by Python 3, for portability.